# Defining global variable for Browserify

Tags: browserify, spine.js

I'm using SpineJS (which exports a commonjs module) and it needs to be available globally because I use it everywhere, but It seems like I have to do `Spine = require('spine')` on every file that uses Spine for things to work.

Is there any way to define `Spine` once to make it globally available?

PS: I'm using Spine as an example, but I'm in general wondering about how to do this with any other library.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Writing `Spine = require('spine')` in each file is the right way to do.

Yet, there are several possibilities by using the `global` or `window` object (browserify sets the `global` object to `window`, which is the global namespace):

- in spine.js: `global.Spine = module.exports`
- in any other .js file bundled by browserify: `global.Spine = require('spine')`
- in a script tag or an .js file referenced by the .html file, after the spine.js file: `window.Spine = require('spine')`

Comment: With common dependencies like jQuery and lodash/underscore, it becomes annoying to clutter half your files with require boilerplate when you're working on large projects. Glad to have the alternatives

Comment: The idea though, is that each of those files is a completely defined unit such that you could theoretically take it out of one project and put it in another, and it's still clear what its dependencies are and (sometimes) even where to find them.  Obviously you can still work around that if you just want to get the absolute smallest files possible, but it helps to think of it as documentation rather than clutter, per se.

Answer (score 18):

First of all, for your example David is correct. Include all dependencies in every module you need it in. It's very verbose, but there is no compile time magic going on which alleviates all sorts of anti patterns and potential future problems.

#### The real answer.

This isn't always practical. Browserify accepts an option called `insertGlobalVars`. On build, each streamed file is scanned for identifiers matching the key names provided and wraps the module in an IIFE containing arguments that resolve each identifier that is not assigned within the module. This all happens before the dependency tree is finalized, which allows you to use require to resolve a dependency.

#### TLDR

Use `insertGlobalVars` option in Browserify.

```
browserify({
  insertGlobalVars: {
    spine: function(file, dir) {
      return 'require("spine")';
    }
  }
});
```

For every file scanned, if an identifier `spine` exists that's not assigned, resolve as `require("spine")`.