# Making jQuery, Backbone, etc global variables in Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, browserify, browserify-shim

I have a relatively large app built with Backbone and Marionette. That means that at the top of every file I have something like:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
```

I know that part of the idea of Browserify is that there are no globals but this seems like a lot of unnecessary boilerplate. What I'd like is to have jQuery, Backbone, Underscore, and Marionette load a global variables as they normally do and just assume everywhere in that they are available. Is there a way to do this in browserify?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480336/defining-global-variable-for-browserify) solution?

Comment: Try https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim

Comment: not really answer but browserify/common.js has forced me to rethink how I'm injecting dependencies. Do I want to require my libraries in every file, or do I want a `main.js` file that requires the libraries once and then mounts all my code onto them?

Answer (score -1):

My preferred option would to take advantage of ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) features and make a file called something like `libraries.js`:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

module.exports = { _, $, Backbone, Marionette };
```

...then at the top of your other files you could just use:

```
// libraries.js should be in /node_modules/, or use ... = require('/path/to/libraries.js');
// This requires ES6 (ECMAScript 2015)
const { _, $, Backbone, Marionette } = require('libraries');
```

This is a little different from what you're asking for, but I don't think you actually want to make these variables pollute the `global` object of your app. You just want to reduce boilerplate.

If you wanted these variables available to other code in the global scope, you could remove the `var` statements from libraries.js (maybe name it `globals.js` in that case) and they'd appear on the `window` object.

Comment: Do you have any link/reference that explains this in better detail? I've never seen `{a, b, c}` as valid syntax