# Using browserify, Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am trying example in http://browserify.org/ and try to make a function call as follows:

My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Browserify</title>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="hello()">test</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

and my javascript is:

```
var unique = require('uniq');

var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];

console.log(unique(data));

function hello(){
    alert("here");
}
```

I did browserify main.js -o bundle.js, so I can use require successfully.

But when I click the button, I have the error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined"

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing that you are seeing your 1, 2, 3, 4, ,5, 6 getting printed at the js console?

Answer (score 14):

Browserifies primary purpose is to make JavaScript modules privately scoped so it has no way to see what you are trying to do.

Try using

```
global.hello = function() { alert("hello");}
```

See [defining global variable for browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480336/defining-global-variable-for-browserify).

In general, this is bad practice and you should instead export public properties out of your module and reference them via the required module reference.

Comment: I did try exporting my function but could not figure out how to import it correctly into my html file.  I exported from main.js like this: `module.exports.beep = function (n) { return n * 1000 }`.  I tried importing into my index.html like this: `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`.  I ran browserify like this: `browserify src/main.js -o public/bundle.js`.  However I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: beep is not defined" when I tried to load index.html in browser.  Using your `global.hello` approach worked!  But I would love to use module reference if possible.

Comment: Do you mean/trying to say that _**During the bundling process Browserify puts the code that we think is in global scope in a new module on its own, so that's why it can't access the globals**_??

Answer (score 2):

just try to use `global.hello = function() { alert("hello");}` in your js file and then build it using **browserify**.