# Getting node modules working in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I need to make one node module run in browser. The node module is [fury.js](https://github.com/apiaryio/fury.js). I tried browserify but when trying to use it it gives error "ReferenceError: fury is not defined". In browserify js/main.js, I only did a 'require' `var fury = require('fury');`. An output file was also generated by browserify but I'm not able to use it in my browser, because of the error mentioned above. I am very novice in nodejs & browserify world, need some help.

Comment: Updating `var fury = require('fury');` to `global.fury = require('fury');` resolved the problem, details can be found here  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480336/defining-global-variable-for-browserify

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install the package locally using npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) in order to be able to use it via browserify:

```
npm install --save fury
```

Comment: earlier I did it without --save option, now I did as you suggested, but no difference. This is the link to the file[link](http://www.filedropper.com/fury) generated by browserify. Command used is : `browserify js/main.js -o js/fury.js`