# Migrate old fashioned Backbone modules to es6 modules

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, babeljs, es6-modules

I have all these modules that are declared in this fashion based on a Global `app` variable which is then bundled via `gulpfile`

*view1.js*

```
var app = app || {}
app.View1 = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

*view2.js*

```
var app = app || {}
app.View1 = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

So I reference between the files using:

```
var app = app || {};
new app.View1();
new app.View2();
```

At this point this approach is obsolete.

Using `babel` infact I would like to compile with `browserify` using new fashion module exports

*view1.js*

```
import Backbone
export default = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

Now, my problem is that I would like to start migrating without editing the old modules ( at least for now ). I tried something like that:

```
import * as _ from "underscore";
import Backbone from "Backbone";
import * as LoginModal from "../views/loginModal";
import Router from "./router";

new LoginModal();
new Router();
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState : true,
    hashChange : false
});
```

The problem is that in `LoginModal` various globals as `_` or `$` are undefined. 
Any idea on how to keep both types of modules and bundle them together?

Answer (score 1):

In your main file you can import `jQuery` and `_` and assign it to `Backbone` like so:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import _ from "underscore";

Backbone.$ = $;
Backbone._ = _;
```

And then in your other files, you can just use `Backbone.$` & `Backbone._` to use `underscore` or `jquery`.

OR only import them as dependencies in the files that use `underscore` or `jQuery`. This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: uhmmm it could work but I would like to avoid modifying all the old files

Comment: well you're going to have to `import _ from "underscore"` and `import $ from "jquery"` in the files that you have used them then. These are the only two options.

Answer (score 0):

You can define some global variables in Browserify options: [Defining global variable for Browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480336/defining-global-variable-for-browserify)

In webpack there's [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) for global modules.