# How to expose an object globally with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I've looked online at how to expose a global variable to the `window` object in Browserify but to no avail. All I found was a *really* dead Stack Overflow question and blogs. Do I *have* to do this manually or is there a `config` option for it like Webpack's `libraryTarget` option? **I have looked for the answer**.

Comment: Is `process.env` not good enough for your need  ?

Comment: Sorry... edited now.

Comment: Have you tried `global`? E.g. `global.var = 123`

Comment: Thats not what I'm looking for. I'm asking whether or not browserify has some config flags that exposes an object to the global window object, choosing a name like Webpack's `libraryTarget`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that setting the `insertGlobalVars` property on the browserify options works lovely for this. For anyone else wondering go to

> [Defining global variable for Browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480336/defining-global-variable-for-browserify#answer-34407100).

There's example code, too.